# How to represent the Lyapunov linear matrix inequality

Tags: matrix

Given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, how do I go about representing the Lyapunov's inequality

$$A^T P + P A \prec 0$$

as a canonical linear matrix inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent this as an LMI, you need to work out the multiplication of $A^{T}P$ and $PA$.

Your variable matrix $P$ will be constrained to be symmetric, so it can be written as

$P=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
P_{11} & P_{12} \\
P_{12} & P_{22} 
\end{array}
\right].$

Then

$
A^{T}P=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A_{11}P_{11}+A_{21}P_{12} & A_{11}P_{12}+A_{21}P_{22} \\
A_{12}P_{11}+A_{22}P_{12} & A_{12}P_{12}+A_{22}P_{22} 
\end{array}
\right].$

Similarly,

$
PA=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
P_{11}A_{11}+P_{12}A_{21} & P_{11}A_{12}+P_{12}A_{22} \\
P_{12}A_{11}+P_{22}A_{21} & P_{12}A_{12}+P_{22}A_{22} 
\end{array}
\right].$

Now, we factor out $P_{11}$, $P_{12}$, and $P_{22}$ to get

$A^{T}P+PA=
P_{11}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
2A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{12}  &      0 
\end{array}
\right]
+
P_{12}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
2A_{21}       & A_{11}+A_{22} \\
A_{11}+A_{22} & 2A_{12} 
\end{array}
\right]
+P_{22}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0             & A_{21} \\
A_{21}        & 2A_{22} 
\end{array}
\right].
$

Now, the LMI can be written in standard form as

$P_{11}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-2A_{11} & -A_{12} \\
-A_{12}  &      0 
\end{array}
\right]
+
P_{12}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
-2A_{21}       & -A_{11}-A_{22} \\
-A_{11}-A_{22} & -2A_{12} 
\end{array}
\right]
+P_{22}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0             & -A_{21} \\
-A_{21}        & -2A_{22} 
\end{array}
\right]
\succeq 0
$

Comment: In practice, you're probably better off making use of a tool that can handle the problem formulation for you.  For example, CVX would do this directly for you.